# What's the difference between FBTweakBind and FBTweakValue?

Tags: ios, facebook

I am using FBTweak lib in my iOS project. I wonder is there difference between FBTweakBind and FBTweakValue.

For example:

```
FBTweakBind(self.headerView, alpha, @"Main Screen", @"Header", @"Alpha", 0.85);
```

can rewrite like this:

```
self.headerView.alpha = FBTweakValue( @"Main Screen", @"Header", @"Alpha", 0.85 );
```

so are they just equal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out.

**FBTweakBinding** will refresh the value it's binding. It means that `FBTweak` will call the setter of the property whenever you change the value while app is running.

**FBTweakValue** is just a variable. When program is going through that line of code, the property  will be set. If you change the `FBTweakValue` after where it used, it did nothing, unless that line of code running again.

Answer (score 0):

I am playing with FBTweak lib only since couple of minutes, but from what I understood from the documentation on github, `FBTweakValue` is just setting the value, but `FBTweakBind` is binding the changes to make tweaks update live.

Keep in mind, that both `FBTweakValue` and `FBTweakBind` might behave differently in a release builds

Source: https://github.com/facebook/Tweaks/wiki#bind